# Detecting and Applying Current System Language on HTML 5 App on Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, backbone.js

I am working on a HTML5 app which uses PhoneGap and Backbone JS.

Problem is that Language changed on Android device through settings doesn't get in my HTML 5 app, though i can see it getting changed in independent Browser instance.

To support globalization of the app I am using i18n plugin to select current language for the app. My app works just fine with iOS. However when i try this on Android, language selected by user doesn't get reflected For example if i choose french as my language from system setting and try to see what is the value of window.navigator.language it remains **en** as oppose to **fr**, this gets reflected perfectly on iOS. Just for your information ,as recommended by PhoneGap, on Android I am calling

```
`public class myApp extends DroidGap {
    private String pageURl = "somepath";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl(pageUrl); // this will load my app's main html page.
    }
}`
```

Could somebody please help me in figuring out what the problem is?

Thanks 
Big O

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try fetching language from user agent string with following patch, it should work:

```
    var lang;
    if (navigator
            && navigator.userAgent
            && (lang = navigator.userAgent
                    .match(/android.*\W(\w\w)-(\w\w)\W/i))) {
        lang = lang[1];
    }

    if (!lang && navigator) {
        if (navigator.language) {
            lang = navigator.language;
        } else if (navigator.browserLanguage) {
            lang = navigator.browserLanguage;
        } else if (navigator.systemLanguage) {
            lang = navigator.systemLanguage;
        } else if (navigator.userLanguage) {
            lang = navigator.userLanguage;
        }
        lang = lang.substr(0, 2);
    }

    console.log("current language is", lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

Selected answer doesn't seem to work with Cordova-Crosswalk project. Actually with Moto G2 and Cordova-Crosswalk in returns "99" because the userAgent is like this:

[image: userAgent with Cordova-Crosswalk and Moto G2]

I would recommend to use [Cordova Globalization plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization) or make own simple plugin with Java method: Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();